# Spring Data JPA: Using @EntityGraph with EntityGraphType.LOAD doesn't join EAGER @OneToOne Relation

Tags: join, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, entitygraph

I've got the following entity-relations (in Kotlin):

InvoiceEntity:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "contact")
var contactEntity: ContactEntity?,
```

ContactEntity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "contactEntity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
var accountingContactEntity: AccountingContactEntity?
```

AccountingContactEntity:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "contact")
var contactEntity: ContactEntity?
```

When I execute the Query-Method

```
@EntityGraph(
    attributePaths = ["contactEntity"],
    type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD
)
findByDateBetween(...): Set<InvoiceEntity>
```

then I expect that the query contains a `JOIN` for the Contact-Entity and the AccountingContactEntity.

But it is missing for the AccountingContactEntity. Instead, an extra `SELECT` is excecuted for each AccountingContactEntity (N+1). Shouldn't `EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD`  trigger the recognition of the FetchType.EAGER Annotation in the ContactEntity, forcing a `JOIN` for the AccountingContactEntity?

The only thing that works is adding `"contactEntity.accountingContactEntity"` to the EntityGraph.

Isn't there another solution?

By the way, if I'm setting  `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` for the contactEntity of the InvoiceEntity and excecute a normal `find(invoiceId)`, then both tables get joined as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not talking as an expert here, but to eager load related entities, IMHO the EntityGraph `type` should be FETCH. LOAD is used for entity properties.